# Memory leak when deploying the web application

Tags: postgresql, memory-leaks, tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfigdeployWAR
INFO:Deployingwebapplicationarchive.war

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoadervalidateJarFile
INFO:validateJarFile(/usr/local/tomcat/webapps//WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar)-jarnotloaded.SeeServletSpec2.3,section9.7.2.Offendingclass:javax/servlet/Servlet.class

AMorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]registeredtheJDBCdriver[org.postgresql.Driver]butfailedtounregisteritwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Topreventamemoryleak,theJDBCDriverhasbeenforciblyunregistered.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3f929548])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3086ca93])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@615d91c8])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@460e1368])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@461c34c6])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@65ccd71f])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@6b3f686f])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

Morg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@fe1866b])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1f3fe2f2])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b4c8de5])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3ef7c363])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c3cb8e0])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE:Thewebapplication[/]createdaThreadLocalwithkeyoftype[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10](value[com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5d580c58])andavalueoftype[java.lang.Object[]](value[[Ljava.lang.Object;@768db9d8])butfailedtoremoveitwhenthewebapplicationwasstopped.Thisisverylikelytocreateamemoryleak.

org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfigcheckResources
INFO:Undeployingcontext[/]
```

I don't understand the problem. Can any one solve this?

I'm restarting tomcat every time by killing the Java process.

It works fine for 10 to 15 min then it hangs every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with your web application.

1. Don't package any version of servlet-api.jar with your application - the container will provide it.
2. You need to deregister your driver when the web application stops.
3. You need to be more careful with your use of ThreadLocals. A ThreadLocal should never exist outside the scope of a single request.

For more information on the sources of memory leaks and how to fix them read this:
http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Memory-Leaks-60mins.pdf